# How to send multiple AJAX requests and join all the results in an array asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, asynchronous, get

I need to get 100 objects via an ajax request passing an ID, and for that I have an array with 100 ID's, but I cannot send more than 20 ID's per time, so I have to send them 20 by 20 untill I get all the data from server.
What is the best practice to do this in an asynchronous way?

This is how i'm testing it right now, I created a global array and when I get the data from every request, I concatenate that array:

```
window['p'] = [];

function getAllProducts(products) {
    var cont = 0;
    while(cont < products.length){
        (function(cont){
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = '/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search?';

            // concatenate all the id's with the URL
            if (cont === 0){
                url += 'fq=skuId:'+products[0].sku
                for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
                    url+= '&fq=skuId:'+products[i].sku;
                }
            } else {
                for (var i = cont; i < cont + 20; i++) {
                    if (typeof products[i] === 'undefined') {
                        break;
                    }
                    url+= '&fq=skuId:'+products[i].sku;
                }
            }

            req.open('get',url,true);

            req.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (req.status == 200 || req.status == 206 && req.readyState == '4') {
                    var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                    console.log(data);
                    window['p'].push(data);
                }
            }

            req.send(null);
            console.log(req);
        }(cont))
        cont+=20;
    }
}

getAllProducts(productArray);
```

Comment: Is jquery an option?

Comment: @MKougiouris I preffer pure js, but if only the AJAX call is using JQuery, I can convert it :D

Comment: And each ajax can accept up to 20 "&fq=skuId:[SomeID]" ?

Comment: @MKougiouris Yeah, each ajax can accept up to '&fq=skuId:[SomeID]' :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i am back :D so...

We are using jQuery to have cleaner code here and there, and for the convenience it offer for the example, you can native your way through if you want to avoid jQuery

First you will want to create groups of 20 ids to have them ready to iterate over them.
Then you will loop each and send an ajax, we will use jQuery just because we will keep the code cleaner and work with promises at the same time..

```
let products=[{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'},{sku : '151231'},{ sku : '151231'}]; // array of your products here
 let ajaxCallData = [''];
 let counter=0;
 let promises = [];
 let finalDataTable=[];

 // construct a 20 sku's query string for each group of 20's
 for(var i=0,len=products.length-1; i < len; i++)
 {
     if(i%20 == 0 && i > 0){
         ajaxCallData[counter] = ''+ajaxCallData[counter];
         ajaxCallData[++counter]='';      
     }         
     ajaxCallData[counter]+='&fq=skuId:'+products[i].sku;    
}

  // push a promise in the array
  // so we can resolve all of them later on while still fetching them
  $.each(ajaxCallData,function(index){
   promises.push($.get('/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search?'+ajaxCallData[index]));
  })

 // This will resolve when/if all promises have been resolved
 // if any one fails, catch will be fired.
 Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
 // values contains the resolved requests
 // in the original order of the first array ( i am pretty sure about it i think)

  if(values && values.length)
      values.forEach(x => finalDataTable.push(x));// gather all data to the target table

}).catch(function(info){
    // handle errors here
});
```

Take a look at this fiddle here, not completely working but you will be able to apply it to your case ( create a function and pass the original products in etc)

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/55157/)